# Why does my build behave differently when built in Visual Studio 2013 as opposed to 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.net mvc solution built in Visual Studio 2012. Until yesterday it worked properly when building and testing it with Development Server checked under properties -> Web. Today, I switched to Visual Studio 2013 and built my solution. However, when I open the console window in chrome to inspect, I see a javascript error being thrown:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li.active&#13;&#10;`

Why does this error only appear when built in Visual Studio 2013? It does not matter if I use `IIS Express` or `Local IIS` when building.

I've checked with several developers on my team, and they're all experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this was figured out. Turns out the "Browser Link" functionality caused the javascript file to not work properly. Disabling that feature (by clicking the circlular arrow next to the debug-dropdown and un-checking the feature) solved it.